# where does vs2010 saves WebSite property values?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

after  a lot of searching  , i'm trying to find : *where* does vs2010 saves the values for website properties :

[image]

it is not in the SLN , nor PROJ ...

ive heard once it is in <kbd>C:\Users\royi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\Websites.xml</kbd>

but after a testing of changing , i cant see the reflected changes...(even after restart - for flushing...)

so where does vs2010 saves it ?

*p.s. I also tried FileMon... but nothing....*

Comment: @oded yeah.. im certain.... The reason for all this is becuase sometines we move in development to differenct branches... so each time we try to debug  - all vs 2010 mini servers appears ( the yellow little icon near the clock... you know... the iis of vs)  ... and it takes a lot of time to re-configure... so i have to save this file ... and when te custom location is deleted - i can compare it quickly from the saved file... but where is the file being saved ??

Comment: Property pages settings are saved into WebSiteCache/websites.xml

Comment: @AVD as i was saying,. i tested it... and im pretty sure ive read it also ( s i mentioned) - but after testing.... it doesnt change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update :

it does save it in <kbd>C:\Users\royi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\Websites.xml</kbd>

i was searching via Total commander in inside the files but unicode checkbox should have been selected...

here is a sample of data  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DesignTimeData>
    <Website RootUrl="C:\Projects\PersonalBranches\RoyiN\Ensure_Solution\Surveys_Mediator\" CacheFolder="Surveys_Mediator(2)" targetframeworkmoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" sccprovider="SAK" enablesilverlightdebugging="false" scclocalpath="SAK" customserverurl="http://localhost/Surveys_Mediator" addnewitemlang="Visual C#" sccauxpath="SAK" sccprojectname="SAK" vwdport="50006" enablevswebserver="false" _LastAccess="22/05/2012 17:10:20"/>
    <Website RootUrl="C:\Projects\PersonalBranches\RoyiN\Ensure_Solution\Web_ERP_Finance\" CacheFolder="Web_ERP_Finance(2)" targetframeworkmoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" sccprovider="SAK" enablesilverlightdebugging="false" scclocalpath="SAK" customserverurl="http://localhost/Web_ERP_Finance/" addnewitemlang="Visual C#" sccauxpath="SAK" sccprojectname="SAK" vwdport="49995" enablevswebserver="false" _LastAccess="22/05/2012 17:10:16"/>
    <Website RootUrl="C:\Projects\Ensure_Solution\GD_OnlineApplication\" CacheFolder="GD_OnlineApplication(1)" sccprovider="MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe" scclocalpath=".." customserverurl="http://localhost/GD_OnlineApplication" sccauxpath="" addnewitemlang="Visual C#" sccprojectname="&quot;$/Ensure_Solution&quot;, IARCAAAA" vwdport="59009" enablevswebserver="false" _LastAccess="08/11/2011 13:22:03"/>
    <Website RootUrl="C:\Projects\Ensure_Solution\TrafficTesterWeb\" CacheFolder="TrafficTesterWeb(1)" sccprovider="MSSCCI:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe" scclocalpath=".." customserverurl="http://localhost/TrafficTesterWeb" sccauxpath="" addnewitemlang="Visual C#" sccprojectname="&quot;$/Ensure_Solution&quot;, IARCAAAA" vwdport="59021" enablevswebserver="false" _LastAccess="08/11/2011 13:22:05"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On one of my projects, I found it in .csproj.  If you don't see it there, use  the tool I used, Windows Grep 2.3 and search for the value you have saved.  It is a very handy tool for finding specific strings in files that VS search functions may not uncover.

Comment: It is on mine... Either way, Windows Grep will find it, and you don't need a license to try it.  Just download, install and run.  Point it to the top level directory of your solution and it will find the text inside any file.